# Crash when presenting viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to presentViewController but to crashed with following stack trace.
Can some one please check and help.

Code to presentViewController

```
func moveToChatView(){
 SwiftSpinner.show(Strings.loading)

  let destViewController:GroupChatViewController  = UIStoryboard(name:      "GroupChat", bundle:  nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GroupChatViewController") as!    GroupChatViewController
 destViewController.currentRiderRideID = self.riderRideId!
if NSThread.isMainThread() == true{
self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true, completion:   nil)
 }else{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
  self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true, completion:   nil)
   }
 }
}
```

Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x182b482d8 **exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1948140e4 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x182a2f4c0 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding
3  UIKit                          0x1879e01b4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
4  UIKit                          0x1878dc318 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]
5  UIKit                          0x1875c09bc -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
6  UIKit                          0x1875c0928 -[UIViewController view]
7  UIKit                          0x187cb618c -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:]
8  UIKit                          0x1878c60dc -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:]
9  UIKit                          0x1878e2378 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]
10 UIKit                          0x1878e48c8 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke
11 UIKit                          0x1876ae0ec -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
12 Quickride                      0x100451968 partial apply for LiveRideMapViewController.(moveToChatView() -> ()).(closure #1) (LiveRideMapViewController.swift:1868)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x194e91954 _dispatch_client_callout
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x194e9f590 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x194e91954 _dispatch_client_callout
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x194e9620c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
17 CoreFoundation                 0x182aff7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
18 CoreFoundation                 0x182afd8a0 __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x182a292d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x18c47f6fc GSEventRunModal
21 UIKit                          0x187626f40 UIApplicationMain
22 Quickride                      0x100259a70 main (AppDelegate.swift:23)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x194ebea08 start

Comment: Are you sure `GroupChatViewController` is inside your storyboard `GroupChat` and not in `xib` ?

Comment: Can you drop a breakpoint and tell us which line specifically causes the exception?

Comment: Yeah when trying to present GroupChatViewController I am validating thread is in main thread or not , In this flow it is in background thread so it went to else block and once enter into     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
  self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true, completion:   nil)
   }   It is crashed, Is it because current view controller is not available

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule don't use dispatch_**sync** , but instead use dispatch_**async** and you don't have to check if you on the main thread , if it is a UI operation and there is a chance that it will be on a back thread just do dispatch_**async** to main queue which will perform the UI operation on the next run loop on the main queue and the UI will be 'smooth' ,try this:

```
func moveToChatView(){
    SwiftSpinner.show(Strings.loading)

    let destViewController:GroupChatViewController  = UIStoryboard(name:"GroupChat", bundle:  nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GroupChatViewController") as!    GroupChatViewController
    destViewController.currentRiderRideID = self.riderRideId!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
       self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true,completion:nil)
   }
}
```